# how do I print a number less than 1 but greater than 0?

Tags: c#

I am expressing the power method in a script, at one point I am trying to do a negative, which is 1 / final_answer

the thing is it does not print things such as 2^-3 which is .125

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write ("Enter a base number: ");
    string str_x = Console.ReadLine ();
    double x = double.Parse (str_x);

    Console.Write ("Enter an exponent: ");
    string str_n = Console.ReadLine ();
    double n = double.Parse (str_n);

    double final = 1;
    int count = 1;
    while (count != n+1) {
        final = final * x;
        count++;
    }
    if (n < 0)
        final = 1 / final;


    Console.WriteLine(final);
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the Math.Pow call?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `count != Math.Abs(n) + 1` in the `while` condition?

Comment: yes, the assignment says not to

Comment: @MillieSmith I'm pretty sure I meant about Math.Pow.

Comment: @dvnrrs Sorry for the misunderstanding, and I apologize if I (unintentionally) came off as snobby. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the loop

```
int count = 1;
while (count != n + 1)
    final = final * x;
    count++;
}
```

cannot end if `n == -3` since `count` is always positive.

In addition, it could be an endless loop because you compare `int` and `double`

```
double n = float.Parse (str_n);
....
int count = 1;
while (count != n + 1) {
```

You should avoid use of `==` and `!=` with doubles.

Comment: sorry, I updated the scrit to make it double.Parse. I can print out positive exponents but with negatives it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

With negative values of the exponent, your loop never terminates because count will never reach a negative value (or zero), at least until it overflows.

And as others said, read the exponent as an integer, not a double.

Comment: Thanks for you earlier comment! Bedtime for me I guess :) +1 for negative values!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @aevitas Why? It answers the question.